# Pictures across multiple columns

Tags: formatting, diagrams, multicol, newspaper

I am creating a newspaper/pamphlet with three `multicol` columns and I want to be able to put a picture across two of the columns like so:

```
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~~                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~~                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~~                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~~                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~~                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~~                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Can someone please provide:

1. A way to do this with `multicol`, or
2. An alternative package that can accomplish this?

MWE (doesn't really work though):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\lipsum[1-4]
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image-a}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{Label}
\end{figure}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How do you create pull quotes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45709/5764)

Comment: If you need more complex layout than cutting out a few rectangles, I suggest trying flowfram: https://ctan.org/pkg/flowfram . It merges frame-driven layouting with Latex techniques. Sure it has a learning curve, but it's hard to resist this package when designing newspapers and similar.

Comment: Highly related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/512455/two-column-with-a-text-box-in-the-center-wrapping-on-both-sides  The big problem with flowfram is when a paragraph is split over two frames with different widths.

Comment: You can see in Werner's  comment that that pull quotes are tricky in standard  two-columns, with multicol it could be between devilishly complicated and impossible. Latex really was not thinked for [magazine layouts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/283037/magazine-template)  so you may consider also leave the layout in the hands of [Scribus](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/426907/11604).